# Use a variable in a loop to name a data frame in R

Tags: r, loops, dynamic, naming

I have 8 .csv files each containing daily levels for 8 lakes.  I want to create a loop to read each of these files into R and name them accordingly.  How do I get the loop to generate a name for an R data frame?  Below is what I have tried and I understand why it doesn't work on the last line of the loop (but I am not sure of an alternative).  I want the data frames to the named Okareka_daily_levels, Okaro_daily_levels, .... etc.

```
Lake_names <- cbind("Okareka", "Okaro", "Okataina", "Rerewhakaaitu", "Rotokakahi", "Rotomahana", "Tarawera", "Tikitapu")

  
for (i in 1:8){
    name <- Lake_names[i]
    read_file <- gsub(" ", "", paste("Data\\", name, "_daily_levels.csv"))
    write_name <- gsub(" ", "", paste(name, "_daily_levels"))
    write_name <- as_tibble(read.csv(read_file)) # read file with lake elevations
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting `write_name` with each evaluation of the loop, so you're probably getting the contents of only the last lake name (Tikitapu).  The lazy evaluation used in `for` loops probably isn't helping either.  One way to fix this is to convert the `for` loop to an `lapply`:

```
library(tidyverse)

listOfTibbles <- lapply(
                   1:8,
                   function(i) {
                     name <- Lake_names[i]
                     read_file <- gsub(" ", "", paste("Data\\", name, "_daily_levels.csv"))
                     write_name <- gsub(" ", "", paste(name, "_daily_levels"))
                     # Note the edit to the next line: you need a return value.
                     as_tibble(read.csv(read_file)) # read file with lake elevations
                   }
                 )
```

`lapply` returns a list, each element of the list is the result of applying the function defined in its second argument to the elements of the first argument in turn.  So you should get a list of eight tibbles from this code.  To combine the list of tibbles into one tibble, you can

```
oneBigTibble <- listOfTibbles %>% bind_rows()
```

This is untested code as I don't have access to your CSV files.