# Automatically read-in and bind a large set of identically structured files

Tags: r, stringr

I have a large number of identically structured text files all stored in a single folder that I want to **read-in in one go**. I also have a vector with the names of all these files; that vector is called `myFileNames`. Initially, each file has just one column. With the help of this post [How to extract a part of the filename from the `read.table` command and define as a new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77544077/how-to-extract-a-part-of-the-filename-from-the-read-table-command-and-define-a), I'm able to automatically create a second column 'Recording` which contains a part of the file name and serves as a file ID. Here's the function to do this:

```
extract_file_name <- function(fName) {
  read.table(
    fName, 
    comment.char = "", header = FALSE, quote = "", sep = "\t", stringsAsFactors = F, encoding = "UTF-8"
  ) %>% mutate(Rec = str_extract(fName, ".*\\d"))
}
```

This works beautifully for one single file:

```
df <- extract_file_name("[MYPATH]/Jeu1_2016-10-06_entier_NORM_DEF.txt")
```

But I want to perform this operation for a set of more than 100 files while at the same time binding the files together. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Umm, doesn't my `lapply` offer in answer to your previous question give you what you need?  If not, please explain why...  `dsf <- lapply(myListOfFileNames, extract_file_name) %>% bind_rows()`, for example.

Comment: I get an error: `apply(str_c("/Users/chris/Downloads/Corpus Pauscaf-L2 - for R", myFileNames), extract_file_name)
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file '/Users/chris/Downloads/Corpus Pauscaf-L2 - for RJeu1_2016-10-06_entier_NORM_DEF.txt': No such file or directory` NOTE: I've included the path: `"/Users/chris/Downloads/Corpus Pauscaf-L2 - for R"`

Comment: even when outsourcing the path to `setwd("/Users/chris/Downloads/Corpus Pauscaf-L2 - for R/")` I get an error: `Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec, :
line 2 did not have 2 elements`

Comment: When constructing you list of file names, did you set `full.names = FALSE` in your presumed call to `list.files`?  The error messag(s) suggest that there's a problem finding the files.  My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67176171/use-a-variable-in-a-loop-to-name-a-data-frame-in-r) gives a working solution to an essentially identical problem.